# Ansible Tower 3.7.0 Copy Module Fails To Find or Access Directory

Tags: module, ansible, copy

I have an issue with Ansible Tower 3.7.0 (ansible 2.9.7) when using the Copy module I receive this error message:

```
TASK [Copy Installation Directory For CentOS 7] ********************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option
fatal: [devmachine]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '/var/lib/awx/projects/xagt_install/Test_Directory' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

However, that directory path does exist:

```
[root@tower xagt_install]# pwd
/var/lib/awx/projects/xagt_install

[root@tower xagt_install]# ls -Alh
drwxr-xr-x. 2 awx awx   98 Jun 17 12:57 Test_Directory
```

Here is the task/play:

```
- name: Copy Installation Directory For CentOS 7
  copy:
    src: /var/lib/awx/projects/xagt_install/Test_Directory
    dest: /tmp/
    remote_src: no
  when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "7" and 'xagt' in ansible_facts.packages)
```

It appears the "Test_Directory" has the appropriate permissions.  Anyone have an idea as to why this module is reporting it cannot "find or access" the directory?

Comment: Every directory above that also has to be readable and executable by the user running the ansible command.  Check that.

Comment: /var/lib is owned by root, /awx and it's sub-directories are owned by awx.  However, in the Tower Details after I execute the Play it lists: "LAUNCHED BY  admin".  Is that who you are referring to?   If that is the case, "admin" is not a system user and can not be made owner over the Test_Directory so is there a work around for this?

Comment: No, not `admin`, but the account that owns the Tower process.

Comment: That would be awx, which owns everything except /var/lib.  So why can't awx reach a directory it owns?  There's a: "CREDENTIAL ansible" in the Tower Details and ansible is a system user but even after moving the Test_Directory to ansible's home folder and changing the owner from awx to ansible I still get the same error.

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership of `/var/` and `/var/lib`?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x. 19 root root 267 Jun  2 15:44 /var`


`drwxr-xr-x. 37 root root 4.0K Jun 15 08:52 /var/lib`

Answer (score 0):

Disabling:  **Settings --> Jobs --> Enable Job Isolation** fixed my issue and the Copy module works.

[image]

I assume if I left the Job Isolation enabled then I would need to store directories in **/tmp** in order for the Copy module to access them?

[image]

Comment: That's right, if you don't wanted to disable JOB ISOLATION or use /tmp you can add white listed paths to 'PATHS TO EXPOSE TO ISOLATED JOBS' .